# How to config Wildfly Server on OpenShift V3.x

Tags: openshift, wildfly, wildfly-10

So the problem I'm facing now is that I cannot find anyway to config WildFly server on OpenShift v3.x, because when the end of deploy processing it auto deploy welcome-content to the path "/", and it override to my "/" path.

I couldn't find anyway to get the standalone.xml of that server to modify. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: Have you by chance downloaded and read the free eBook https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html so you understand how deploying stuff to OpenShift works. The example in the book uses Wildfly.

Comment: thank you, I'll download it and read. Hope it solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is source-to-image. Here can you found example images for wildfly. https://github.com/openshift-s2i/s2i-wildfly

You only have to add your standlone.xml under contrib/wfcfg/ in your git repo. Than deploy the s2i-wildfly with your git repo.

Here is a example for the first try. https://github.com/openshift/openshift-jee-sample

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I'm almost certain it doesn't work that way. That only is true for the actual builder, not the code repo...